# Getting parameterles public constructor error

Tags: asp.net, .net, simple-injector

> An error occurred when trying to create a  controller of type
>   'ChatBotController'. Make sure that the controller  has a
>   parameterless public constructor.
>
> at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType) ↵   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) ↵   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()

When I try to reach my IFeedbackRepository I get the error aboe. It happens when I put in the constructor in my ChatBotController.cs

```
public class ChatBotController : ApiController
{
    IFeedbackRepository _feedbackRepository;
    public ChatBotController(IFeedbackRepository feedbackRepository)
    {
        _feedbackRepository = feedbackRepository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostQuestion([FromBody]string message) //TODO: make sure that webapi will search the message in the body of the http request
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm using both MVC and Api which I both resolve in my Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    DependencyConfig.RegisterWebApiDependencies();
    DependencyConfig.RegisterMvcDependencies();
}
```

This is my DependencyConfig.cs for both MVC and Api:

```
public static void RegisterWebApiDependencies()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

    container.Register<IAnswerGenerator, PxlAnswerGenerator>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<ChatBotDbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<IFeedbackRepository, FeedbackDbRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    container.Verify();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

}

public static void RegisterMvcDependencies()
{
    var container = new Container();

    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

    container.Register<IFeedbackRepository, FeedbackDbRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<ChatBotDbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    container.Verify();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like the second call to SetResolver replaces the first one. Are you able to comment out the second call and see what happens?

Comment: THe error is very clear, you need a contructor without any parameters: public ChatBotController() {}. Looking it your code this contructor is not present.

Comment: @Steve Obviously all mvc related things don't work when I do that but when I try to send a POST request to the same url it still gives me the same error message.

Comment: @Aldert yes the error is clear, but it shouldn't happen. The DI infrastructure should provide the required parameter to the constructor. But in some way this doesn't happen

Comment: @Steve, you are saying the error is incorrect?

Comment: @SinanSamet And if you invert the order of the two calls to the register?

Comment: I clearly see a ChatBotController without a parameterless contructor, it seems the DI is wanting one (most likely to create this object). I would go with a parameterless contructor and test once more.

Comment: I still get the same error but the mvc dependency isn't working anymore. So like you said it replaces the other.

Comment: @Aldert it shoudn't happen. Dependency Injection containers should provide the parameters required from the constructor after you have registerd the interface

Comment: @SinanSamet looking at the docs for simple-injectior and serching for the word _resolver_ provides two interesting link on how to initialize the resolver for MVC and WebAPI

Comment: @Steve with you now..Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: It seems that for the WebApi you need to call _new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);_

Comment: You're right! I was injecting the web api the wrong way I forgot to `RegisterWebApiController()` and set the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`! Thanks a lot if you can post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation of Simple-Injector](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html?highlight=resolver) when you want to initialize the resolver for the WebApi part of your registration you need to call

```
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
container.Verify();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you calling   container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);  in RegisterWebApiDependencies(). This is required.

You may want to review the simpleinjector documentation for integrating with ASP.NET Web API and MVC here:

https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html

Also the documentation above has the container/DI setup at the beginning of application_start(). If the above change alone does not work, you may want to try putting the following two lines at the start of application_start():

DependencyConfig.RegisterWebApiDependencies();
DependencyConfig.RegisterMvcDependencies();